# How to read in German these mathematical symbols (f′,f″,f‴,∘,ã ,â,...)?

Tags: mathematics

How to read the mathematical notation of the small list below, say in a blackboard-talk. Notice that I'm not asking for the meaning, but the name of the symbol attached to "the letter" is what matters:

> **Example.** The symbol *a'* (*a prime*) reads *a Strich* in German.

---

Bei einem Vortrag oder Vorlesung an der Tafel will man vielleicht nicht ständig die Definition wiederholen. Etwa anstelle der vollständigen Definition von *f'*, nennt man oft das Zeichnen:

> **Beispiel:** *f'* lautet *f Strich* (ich frage nicht nach dessen Bedeutung).

Wie liest man auf Deutsch die folgenden Zeichnen?

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

- *f'*, *f′* – »f Strich«
- *f''*, *f″* – »f Zweistrich«
- *f'''*, *f‴* – »f Dreistrich«
- *f ∘ g* – »f Kringel g«, »f Kuller g«, »f verknüpft [mit] g«, »f nach g«
- *ã* – »a Schlange«, »a Tilde«
- *â* – »a Dach«
- *c<sub>0</sub>* – »c Null«, »c unten null«, »c Index null«
- *c<sup>0</sup>* – »c hoch null« or (depending on meaning): »c oben null«, »c oberer Index null«
- *ẋ* – »x Punkt«
- *ẍ* – »x Zweipunkt«
- *x̄* – »x Quer«
- *x**, *x⃰* – »x Stern«

Comment: @c.p. Man wird es verstehen, geläufig eher nicht. Tilde wird man im Zweifel auch schnell lernen. Statt *zweistrich* und *dreistrich* sage ich schon mal *Strichstrich* und *Strichstrichstrich.* Und Diminutive (*b Dacherl, a Schlangerl*) kommen immer vor.

Comment: *Dacherl* und *Schlangerl* sind ausschließlich bairisch (Bayern und Österreich). *Strichstrich* hört man tatsächlich immer wieder, aber es ist halt etwas schwerer auszusprechen. *Hut* statt *Dach* ist definitiv nicht gebräuchlich, außer vielleicht bei Ausländern und USA-Rückkehrern.

Comment: Ich kenne auch für f' den Ausdruck f gestrichen und für f'' kenne ich f doppelt/zweifach gestrichen, usw..

Comment: Ich kenne f', f'', ähnlich wie @Martin-マーチン, als "f zweigestrichen", "f dreigestrichen".

Comment: Ich kann mich nicht erinnern, *gestrichen, zweigestrichen, dreigestrichen* so jemals außerhalb der Musik gehört zu haben. Für Formeln kommt mir das auch viel zu lang und schwerfällig vor, um plausibel zu sein. Kann natürlich immer mal sein, dass Musiker Formeln so aussprechen, weil es für sie so am natürlichsten scheint.

Comment: @HansAdler: Ich bin zwar Mathematik-interessierter Österreicher, aber *Dacherl* und *Schlangerl* habe ich noch nie gehört.

Comment: @KevinDreßler: Ich muss Hans Adler recht geben: *gestrichen*, *zweigestrichen* habe ich in einem mathematischen Kontext noch nie gehört. Das kenne ich nur aus der Musik, zur Kennzeichnung von Tönen aus unterschiedlichen Oktaven.