# Wie heißt dieses kreisförmige Symbol auf Deutsch?

Tags: single-word-request

Ich bin schon ziemlich oft diesem Symbol begegnet: ○. (Ich hoffe, dass es sichtbar ist. Es ist im Prinzip ein kleiner Kreis mit schwarzem Rand und weißer Füllung. Der LaTeX-Befehl lautet `\circ`.) Bisher habe ich es immer mit *Kringel* bezeichnet, aber heute habe ich eine vollkommen andere Bezeichnung gehört. Das hörte sich nach *Kola* oder *Kolon* an, aber ich konnte das Wort akustisch nicht so gut verstehen, also gibt es wahrscheinlich da Abweichungen.

Falls es diese Bezeichnung gibt, woher kommt sie (z.B. anderes Wort für Kreis?) und wie wird sie wirklich geschrieben?

Comment: Vielleicht *Kuller*?

Comment: @CarstenS Ja, ich glaub schon. Jedenfalls passt das zu dem Wiktionary-Eintrag hier: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Kuller Danke!

Comment: Ähnlich: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/26196

Comment: Unicode: '[WHITE CIRCLE' (U+25CB)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25CB/index.htm)

Comment: Unicode für die von @chirlu zitierte Antwort: ['RING OPERATOR' (U+2218)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2218/index.htm)

Comment: Siehe auch: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verkettungszeichen

Comment: Schreibt blos keine Antwort!

Comment: @falkb In der Frage kommt das Zeichen in der Tat auch vor, es fehlt aber noch eine Antwort, die dieses spezielle Synonym enthält.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wie man das Symbol nennt, hängt vom Zusammenhang ab, da es in vielfältigen Bedeutungen verwendet wird. Hier beziehe ich mich auf die Mathematik.

Beispiele:

- Wenn das Symbol wie [hier](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/26196/how-to-read-in-german-these-mathematical-symbols-f-f-f-%E2%88%98-a%CC%83-a%CC%82) für die Verknüpfung von Funktionen verwendet wird, kann man es wie dort angegeben als "nach" lesen.
- Wird es für das [Hadamardprodukt](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Hadamard_product#Hadamard_multiplication) verwendet, werden sicher die meisten es auf Deutsch als "mal" lesen.
- Das Symbol wird auch oft von Autoren in der Mathematik für ad-hoc-Definitionen verwendet; was man dafür sagt, hängt dann davon ab, worum es geht.